# Numerical Comparison in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I did calculation and got the following numbers

0.739128438976901   0.739128438976900

I want MATLAB to consider that they are equal, but MATLAB recognized that the first one was greater than the second.  How can I make MATLAB consider them as they are equal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a whole lot about Matlab (I'm more of a Mathematica guy myself), but it seems there is a `roundn(x,n)` function which rounds an element `x` to the nearest multiple of 10^`n`. Perhaps this could be used here.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 42
y = 42.00001
if abs(x-y) < tolerance
    % do something
end
```

The setting for `tolerance` is up to you.